# Drupal select list key in template file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-templates

How would I go about getting the `key` of a select list field in a view template (Row style output)?

The field is added to my view and hidden from display. It contains stuff like:

> red|Red
>   green|Green
>   blue|Blue

How can I get the selected key (ie. `red`) for the field in the template?

I was able to print it using:

```
$view->field['field_color']->view->result[0]->field_field_color[0]['raw']['value']
```

but I wonder if there is an easier way to get that key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row->field_field_color[0]['raw']['value'];
```